# Segmentation fault error with ruby 1.9.3 when doing bundle install for Rails 3.2 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I just installed Rails using [Rails_App_Composer](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails_apps_composer), and when I try to run `bundle install` I am getting this error:

```
Resolving deltas: 100% (17189/17189), done.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/./.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0046 p:---- s:0243 b:0243 l:000242 d:000242 CFUNC  :connect
c:0045 p:0011 s:0240 b:0240 l:001ab0 d:000239 BLOCK  /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799
c:0044 p:0031 s:0238 b:0238 l:000237 d:000237 METHOD /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:54
c:0043 p:0026 s:0226 b:0226 l:000225 d:000225 METHOD /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99
c:0042 p:0485 s:0220 b:0220 l:001ab0 d:001ab0 METHOD /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799
c:0041 p:0011 s:0212 b:0212 l:000211 d:000211 METHOD /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:755
c:0040 p:0089 s:0209 b:0209 l:000208 d:000208 METHOD /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:750
c:0039 p:0340 s:0206 b:0206 l:000205 d:000205 METHOD /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:224
c:0038 p:0157 s:0198 b:0198 l:000197 d:000197 METHOD /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:358
c:0037 p:0081 s:0184 b:0184 l:000183 d:000183 METHOD /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:145
c:0036 p:0105 s:0176 b:0176 l:000175 d:000175 METHOD /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:173
c:0035 p:0141 s:0166 b:0166 l:000165 d:000165 METHOD /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:132
c:0034 p:0178 s:0156 b:0156 l:000155 d:000155 METHOD /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:70
c:0033 p:0042 s:0148 b:0148 l:000137 d:000147 BLOCK  /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/source.rb:234
c:0032 p:---- s:0143 b:0143 l:000142 d:000142 FINISH
c:0031 p:---- s:0141 b:0141 l:000140 d:000140 CFUNC  :each
c:0030 p:0079 s:0138 b:0138 l:000137 d:000137 METHOD /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/source.rb:232
c:0029 p:0018 s:0128 b:0128 l:000127 d:000127 METHOD /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/source.rb:165
c:0028 p:0025 s:0124 b:0124 l:000123 d:000123 METHOD /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/source.rb:70
c:0027 p:0059 s:0121 b:0120 l:000102 d:000119 BLOCK  /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:191
c:0026 p:---- s:0116 b:0116 l:000115 d:000115 FINISH
c:0025 p:---- s:0114 b:0114 l:000113 d:000113 CFUNC  :each
c:0024 p:0043 s:0111 b:0111 l:000102 d:000110 BLOCK  /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:188
c:0023 p:0020 s:0107 b:0107 l:000106 d:000106 METHOD /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/index.rb:9
c:0022 p:0031 s:0103 b:0103 l:000102 d:000102 METHOD /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:184
c:0021 p:0120 s:0100 b:0097 l:000096 d:000096 METHOD /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:178
c:0020 p:0027 s:0092 b:0092 l:000091 d:000091 METHOD /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:113
c:0019 p:0047 s:0086 b:0086 l:000085 d:000085 METHOD /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:108
c:0018 p:0303 s:0083 b:0083 l:000082 d:000082 METHOD /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/installer.rb:81
c:0017 p:0033 s:0077 b:0077 l:000076 d:000076 METHOD /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/installer.rb:14
c:0016 p:0995 s:0070 b:0070 l:000069 d:000069 METHOD /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:227
c:0015 p:0036 s:0061 b:0061 l:000060 d:000060 METHOD /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22
c:0014 p:0071 s:0055 b:0055 l:000054 d:000054 METHOD /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118
c:0013 p:0221 s:0049 b:0049 l:000048 d:000048 METHOD /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263
c:0012 p:0082 s:0038 b:0038 l:000037 d:000037 METHOD /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386
c:0011 p:0017 s:0032 b:0032 l:000025 d:000031 BLOCK  /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/bin/bundle:14
c:0010 p:0009 s:0030 b:0030 l:000029 d:000029 METHOD /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:4
c:0009 p:0062 s:0026 b:0026 l:000025 d:000025 TOP    /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/bin/bundle:14
c:0008 p:---- s:0024 b:0024 l:000023 d:000023 FINISH
c:0007 p:---- s:0022 b:0022 l:000021 d:000021 CFUNC  :load
c:0006 p:0127 s:0018 b:0018 l:000c18 d:002640 EVAL   /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/bundle:19
c:0005 p:---- s:0015 b:0015 l:000014 d:000014 FINISH
c:0004 p:---- s:0013 b:0013 l:000012 d:000012 CFUNC  :eval
c:0003 p:0101 s:0007 b:0007 l:000c18 d:002630 EVAL   /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:000c18 d:000c18 TOP   

-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/bin/bundle:14:in `<top (required)>'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:4:in `with_friendly_errors'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/bin/bundle:14:in `block in <top (required)>'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:227:in `install'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/installer.rb:14:in `install'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/installer.rb:81:in `run'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:108:in `resolve_remotely!'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:113:in `specs'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:178:in `resolve'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:184:in `index'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/index.rb:9:in `build'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:188:in `block in index'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:188:in `each'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:191:in `block (2 levels) in index'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/source.rb:70:in `specs'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/source.rb:165:in `fetch_specs'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/source.rb:232:in `remote_specs'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/source.rb:232:in `each'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/source.rb:234:in `block in remote_specs'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:70:in `specs'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:132:in `fetch_remote_specs'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:173:in `fetch_dependency_remote_specs'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:145:in `fetch'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:358:in `request'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:224:in `connection_for'
/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:750:in `start'
/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:755:in `do_start'
/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `connect'
/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:54:in `timeout'
/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `block in connect'
/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `connect'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------

   See Crash Report log file under ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter or
   /Library/Logs/CrashReporter, for the more detail of.

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/bundle

* Loaded features:

    0 enumerator.so
    1 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/enc/encdb.bundle
    2 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/enc/trans/transdb.bundle
    3 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults.rb
    4 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/rbconfig.rb
    5 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/deprecate.rb
    6 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/exceptions.rb
    7 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb
    8 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb
    9 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/version.rb
   10 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/requirement.rb
   11 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/platform.rb
   12 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb
   13 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/path_support.rb
   14 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb
   15 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/etc.bundle
   16 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb
   17 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/pathname.bundle
   18 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/pathname.rb
   19 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/syntax_error.rb
   20 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/psych.bundle
   21 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/stringio.bundle
   22 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/node.rb
   23 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/stream.rb
   24 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/document.rb
   25 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/sequence.rb
   26 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/scalar.rb
   27 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/mapping.rb
   28 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/alias.rb
   29 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes.rb
   30 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/streaming.rb
   31 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/visitor.rb
   32 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/strscan.bundle
   33 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/scalar_scanner.rb
   34 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb
   35 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/emitter.rb
   36 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb
   37 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/json/ruby_events.rb
   38 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/json_tree.rb
   39 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/depth_first.rb
   40 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors.rb
   41 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/handler.rb
   42 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/tree_builder.rb
   43 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/parser.rb
   44 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/omap.rb
   45 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/set.rb
   46 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/coder.rb
   47 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/core_ext.rb
   48 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/date_core.bundle
   49 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/date/format.rb
   50 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/date.rb
   51 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/deprecated.rb
   52 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/stream.rb
   53 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/json/yaml_events.rb
   54 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/json/tree_builder.rb
   55 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/json/stream.rb
   56 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/handlers/document_stream.rb
   57 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb
   58 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb
   59 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/psyched_yaml.rb
   60 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/gem_helpers.rb
   61 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/match_platform.rb
   62 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb
   63 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/config_file.rb
   64 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/psych_additions.rb
   65 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/psych_tree.rb
   66 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/syck_hack.rb
   67 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb
   68 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/version.rb
   69 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler.rb
   70 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.0.2/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb
   71 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/core_ext/hash_with_indifferent_access.rb
   72 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/core_ext/ordered_hash.rb
   73 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/error.rb
   74 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/shell.rb
   75 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb
   76 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/parser/argument.rb
   77 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/parser/arguments.rb
   78 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/parser/option.rb
   79 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/parser/options.rb
   80 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/parser.rb
   81 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb
   82 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/util.rb
   83 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb
   84 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb
   85 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb
   86 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb
   87 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/ftp.rb
   88 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/http.rb
   89 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/https.rb
   90 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/ldap.rb
   91 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/ldaps.rb
   92 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/mailto.rb
   93 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri.rb
   94 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/core_ext/file_binary_read.rb
   95 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb
   96 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/actions/create_file.rb
   97 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/actions/create_link.rb
   98 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/actions/directory.rb
   99 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/erb.rb
  100 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/time.rb
  101 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb
  102 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/actions/file_manipulation.rb
  103 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/actions/inject_into_file.rb
  104 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/actions.rb
  105 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendored_thor.rb
  106 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/user_interaction.rb
  107 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb
  108 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb
  109 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/delegate.rb
  110 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tmpdir.rb
  111 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/thread.rb
  112 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tempfile.rb
  113 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/shell/basic.rb
  114 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/shell/color.rb
  115 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/ui.rb
  116 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/settings.rb
  117 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb
  118 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/socket.bundle
  119 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/socket.rb
  120 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb
  121 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb
  122 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/zlib.bundle
  123 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb
  124 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/faster.rb
  125 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/cgi/core.rb
  126 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/cgi/cookie.rb
  127 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/cgi/util.rb
  128 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/cgi.rb
  129 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb
  130 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/vendored_persistent.rb
  131 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb
  132 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.0.2/lib/rubygems-bundler/wrapper.rb
  133 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.0.2/lib/rubygems-bundler/rubygems_bundler_installer.rb
  134 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb
  135 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/command.rb
  136 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/command_manager.rb
  137 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/f_sync_dir.rb
  138 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_header.rb
  139 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/enc/iso_8859_1.bundle
  140 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_input.rb
  141 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_output.rb
  142 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_reader/entry.rb
  143 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_reader.rb
  144 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_writer.rb
  145 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package.rb
  146 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/format.rb
  147 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb
  148 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/configure_builder.rb
  149 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb
  150 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/rake_builder.rb
  151 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext.rb
  152 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/require_paths_builder.rb
  153 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb
  154 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.0.2/lib/rubygems-bundler/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb
  155 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/digest.bundle
  156 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/digest.rb
  157 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/digest/sha1.bundle
  158 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/set.rb
  159 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb
  160 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/dependency.rb
  161 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/dsl.rb
  162 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb
  163 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/errors.rb
  164 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/text.rb
  165 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb
  166 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/gem_installer.rb
  167 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/source.rb
  168 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb
  169 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/forwardable.rb
  170 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb
  171 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_list.rb
  172 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb
  173 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/environment.rb
  174 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/installer.rb
  175 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/index.rb
  176 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bundler/gems/rails_admin-7bfad1add513/lib/rails_admin/version.rb
  177 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/resolver.rb
  178 /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb
  179 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/openssl.bundle
  180 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/bn.rb
  181 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/cipher.rb
  182 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/config.rb
  183 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/digest.rb
  184 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb
  185 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/fcntl.bundle
  186 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/ssl-internal.rb
  187 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/x509-internal.rb
  188 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl.rb
  189 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/https.rb

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abort trap: 6
```

1. I am not used to seeing such verbose error messages - is this a Rails 3.2.x thing or is there a gem specific to Rails_App_Composer that is producing these verbose error messages?
2. Any thoughts on what might be causing this issue and how can I fix it? I am running `ruby-1.9.3p194`.
3. When I tried the stable version of `ruby-1.9.2` it gave me another error, but still didn't work. Let me know if you need me to paste that error too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a petty messed up ruby install at one point that was giving segmentation faults. I did

```
rvm implode
```

And started from scratch and in about an hour everything was working again

Comment: I'm getting the same symptom using Ruby installed using ruby-build and with Ruby environment configured using rbfu-env. Strangely, I get the error in one app but not in another, and they're using the same Ruby & gemset (rbfu doesn't create/manage multiple gemsets per Ruby). I even tried removing all traces of a gem used by the app that's working to prove that it still works when it has to retrieve a gem to install it.

Answer (score 3):

I found this less impactful than the other answer, implosion isnt always an option, especially in a Dev environment..snippets taken from this blog https://coderwall.com/p/f4hyqw

The version of OpenSSL that ships with OS X 10.6 and 10.7 is older and causes this issue.

There are a number of options solve this. Here a few:

## MacPorts

```
port selfupdate
port install openssl
port install libyaml
```

RVM

> rvm install 1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=/opt/local --with-opt-dir=/opt/local

rbenv

> CONFIGURE_OPTS='--with-openssl-dir=/opt/local --with-opt-dir=/opt/local' rbenv install 1.9.3-p194

## Homebrew

```
brew update
brew install openssl
```

RVM

> rvm install 1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl`

rbenv

> CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl`" rbenv install 1.9.3-p194

## RVM

```
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

Comment: I tried your instructions for RVM but I keep hanging on 'Installing required packages: gcc46..|'  Rvm implode is an option for me and I have tried like a dozen times and cant get it sorted.  I made a post about it.  If you could help I would be so happy.  This is going on day three trying to figure this thing out.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27024844/segmentation-fault-when-i-run-rails-s-cant-compile-nokogiri?noredirect=1#comment42580775_27024844

Comment: That doesnt really look related, but i would try installing the version of gcc46 that in needs independantly and then try it out again.. gcc is the gnu c compiler. see here...looks like youre not the only one! ;) https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2133

Comment: Yeah I did brew install gcc46 seperately from my install of the ruby as well and it took about 10 min for that library alone.  Also I read that post in my 3 days in pergatory.  That poor guy keeps telling people not to use the clang flag and no one listens lol.