# Segmentation fault when I run rails S (cant compile nokogiri)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have been in configuration hell for two days and I have tried just about everything on Stack Overflow to fix it.  I feel like some of the stuff I have tried may have made things worse. I was using RVM, then I tried using rbenv, and now I am back to using RVM again.  I am not sure if there are remnants of rbenv that are causing this or what but I followed the instructions to remove it completely.

The error I am getting currently is here:

https://gist.github.com/EvanTedesco/d4288cfb1f8dfc5a1e03

ruby -v:

```
ruby 1.9.3p547 (2014-05-14 revision 45962) [x86_64-darwin13.4.0]
```

rails -v:

```
Rails 3.2.19
```

xcode-select -p:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

gem env:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.5 (2014-11-13 patchlevel 273) [x86_64-darwin14.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/acumendigital/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/acumendigital/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/acumendigital/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/acumendigital/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-14
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/acumendigital/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5
     - /Users/acumendigital/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["https://rubygems.org/", "http://rubygems.org"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
     - http://rubygems.org
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/acumendigital/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin
     - /Users/acumendigital/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/bin
     - /Users/acumendigital/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /user/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /user/local/bin
     - /usr/local/git/bin
     - /Users/acumendigital/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin
     - /opt/nginx/sbin
     - /Users/acumendigital/.rvm/bin
```

rvm info:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p547@ums:

  system:
    uname:       "Darwin Evans-MacBook-Pro.local 13.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Sun Aug 17 19:50:11 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.115.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64"
    system:      "osx/10.9/x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)"
    zsh:         "/bin/zsh => zsh 5.0.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.0)"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.26.3 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "8 minutes 33 seconds ago"
    path:         "/Users/acumendigital/.rvm"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "1.9.3p547"
    date:         "2014-05-14"
    platform:     "x86_64-darwin13.4.0"
    patchlevel:   "2014-05-14 revision 45962"
    full_version: "ruby 1.9.3p547 (2014-05-14 revision 45962) [x86_64-darwin13.4.0]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/Users/acumendigital/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ums"
    ruby:         "/Users/acumendigital/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/Users/acumendigital/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/Users/acumendigital/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/Users/acumendigital/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/Users/acumendigital/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/Users/acumendigital/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ums/bin:/Users/acumendigital/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@global/bin:/Users/acumendigital/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin:/Users/acumendigital/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/user/sbin:/sbin:/user/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/acumendigital/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin:/opt/nginx/sbin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/Users/acumendigital/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ums"
    GEM_PATH:     "/Users/acumendigital/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ums:/Users/acumendigital/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/Users/acumendigital/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547"
    IRBRC:        "/Users/acumendigital/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       "ums"
```

Honestly I have no Idea what else to try.  Any help is appreciated greatly.

Comment: can you post your server log output? You probably need to install a system lib file for it to work like libxml2 or something.

Comment: You can obviously compile Nokogiri because that's the compiled library that's crashing. You have some other problem. Have you tried Rails 2.1.x?

Comment: Don't put your error information on another site. *WHEN* that link breaks, because they always do, your question won't mean much to anyone searching for a similar answer. Add the output of `gem env` and `rvm info` to your question.

Comment: @ the Tin Man I wanted to add the output to the post but there is too much for the 8000 character limit.  Is there a part of the error message that is most important that I should include?  I have updated the post with the other info you requested.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by post the server log output, I am getting the error when I try to run the server.  It says for more info check ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter   or /Library/Logs/CrashReporter neither of which exist on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried the steps provided by the tin man and I was still getting the seg fault.  I finally got access to a senior dev and he determined that the problem was that my open ssl was not configured properly.  I fixed the issue with

```
brew link --force openssl
```

then I removed and reinstalled the gemsets and rubies.  All good now.  Thank you to everyone who took time to answer my question and I hope this helps someone else.  Special thanks to the Tin Man for taking the time to write that detailed response.

I also noticed that when I was bundling that I was getting

```
Your bundle is complete!
It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
```

so I deleted ./vendor/bundle with

```
rm -rf ./vendor/bundle
```

and rebundled.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that your `gem env` says you're running Ruby 2.1.5:

```
- RUBY VERSION: 2.1.5 (2014-11-13 patchlevel 273) [x86_64-darwin14.0]
```

while your `ruby -v` shows 1.9.3:

```
ruby 1.9.3p547 (2014-05-14 revision 45962) [x86_64-darwin13.4.0]
```

That tells me your system is really mixed up.

First, capture the list of current gems in your Ruby environment by running:

```
gem list --no-version > ~/gem_list
```

That stores the list of gems currently installed without version numbers in the "gem_list" file at your user's home directory.

Next, I'd recommend doing an `rvm implode`, then exit from your shell and reopen a terminal window. Run

```
grep rvm ~/.bash_profile
```

and look for lines where RVM is being initialized. Delete those from your ~/.bash_profile.

Then, look for lines mentioning rbenv in the same file:

```
grep rbenv ~/.bash_profile
```

and remove them.

Then reinstall RVM by following the directions at http://rvm.io/rvm/install. Read through the directions carefully and follow the directions for doing a single-user installation. Once RVM finishes installing, read the text it outputs and do what it says about setting up your ~/.bash_profile.

At that point you should be able to install a Ruby using:

```
rvm install 2.1.5
```

Once that finishes run:

```
rvm use 2.1.5 --default
```

At that point RVM and your environment should be happy and you can reinstall gems. Run:

```
xargs gem install --conservative < ~/gem_list
```

Gem should chug away, and reinstall the gems you'd previously installed. Eventually it'll stop and if everything looks good you can delete the list of gems using:

```
rm ~/gem_list
```

Note: You are running a Mac OS X machine, and Apple preinstalls Ruby on it. *Never* use `sudo` to install any gems or try to remove the Ruby Apple installs. They put it there to make it possible to run some code, and it's OK for you to run things with it too, but treat it as belonging to the system. That's why we use RVM, to have a version of Ruby we can safely mess with, without running the risk of breaking the default one.

There are many tutorials and blogs on the internet purporting to tell us how to install RVM on our machines, but most of them are out of date, so ignore them. Instead, follow what the RVM authors wrote on their website. The installation page says:

> External tutorials
>
> Note that that any outside tutorials are NOT supported whether they work or not. Tutorials are great, however we have spent massive amounts of man hours debugging the installation process. Please use the install process(es) from this site only, as this is the only supported installation types and methods.